# Conditions for $a,b \in \mathbb R$, such that $0 \in \mathbb R^2$ is exponentially stable for the system : $x_1^+=x_2, x_2^+=ax_1 + bx_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, stationary-point

**Exercise :**

> Find competent and necessary conditions for $a,b \in \mathbb R$, such that $0 \in \mathbb R^2$ is an exponentially stable stationary point for the the linear dynamical system of discrete time :
> $$x_1^+=x_2$$
> $$x_2^+=ax_1 + bx_2$$

**Discussion :**

We have just been introduced to such matters on our Dynamical Systems course and I do not have a lot of experience regarding such a problem, which means I didn't know how to proceed. I did though some research regarding exponential stability, which is listed below.

Going over exponential stability in dynamical system matters, I found the following definition and theorem on internet :

> ***Definition (Exponential Stability, rate of convergence) :***
>
> The equilibrium point $x^* = 0$ is an exponentially stable equilibrium point of the dynamical system :
> $$\dot{x} = f(x,t)$$
> $$x(t_0)=x_0$$
> $$x \in \mathbb R^n$$
> if there exist constants $a,m >0$ and $\epsilon >0$ such that :
> $$\| x(t)\| \leq me^{-a(t-t_0)}\| x(t_0)\|$$
> for all $\|x(t_0)\|\leq\epsilon$ and $t\geq t_0$. The largest constant $a$ is called *rate of convergence*.

---

> ***Exponential Stability Theorem :***
> The point $x^* =0$ is an exponentially stable equilibrium point of $\dot{x} = f(x,t)$ if and only if there exist an $\epsilon > 0$ and a function $V(x,t)$ which satisfies :
> $$a_1\|x\|^2 \leq V(x,t) \leq a_2 \|x\|^2$$
> $$\dot{V}(x,t) \leq -a_3\| x \|^2$$
> $$\bigg\|\frac{\partial V(x,t)}{\partial x}\bigg\| \leq a_4\|x\|$$
> for some positive constants $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ and $\|x\| \leq \epsilon$.

Now, I can say that the theorem looks a bit like the *Lyapunov Stability* ones (correct me if I'm wrong) but I can't seem on how I should proceed on the particular exercise listed up above. I would appreciate some thorough help regarding the particular problem and its solution, to get some comfort with such problems over exponential stability.

Comment: So does e.g. $x^+$ mean the derivative $x'$ of $x$ with respect to an independent variable like $t$ (time)?

Comment: No! Otherwise, one would not invoke "discrete time".

Comment: Did's comment is correct, I was wrong for saying yes. Variables cannot be independent (since we have a system that both functions depend on each other) and also the derivative cannot be with respect to time since this is a discrete time system as mentioned.

Comment: Since this is a linear discrete-time system of the form $x(k+1)=Ax(k)$ with $x(k)=[x_1(k),x_2(k)]^T$, for exponential stability you only need the eigenvalues of $A$ to lie within the unit circle.

Comment: @CTNT Hi and thanks a lot for your comment. Well, then that's an easy case, as one would just define $a,b$ such that $|λ_1|,|λ_2| \leq 1$ (denoting eigenvalues). What's the mathematical instance of the definition and the theorem mentioned though ?

Comment: Note that recursively $x(k)=A^kx(0)$. If you consider the Jordan decomposition of $A=T\Lambda T^{-1}$ then $A^k=T\Lambda^k T^{-1}$. The  matrix $\Lambda^k$ is either a diagonal matrix with elements $\lambda_1^k$, $\lambda_2^k$ or an  upper triangular (for a multiple eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ with Jordan block of dimension 2) with  nonzero elements $\lambda_1^k$, $k\lambda_1^k $. This converges to zero only if $\max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_2|\}<1$.